# Understanding an "obvious" deduction in analysis

Tags: real-analysis, limits

In [Elementary topology](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7U8-rs-S2boC&dq=n%20fold%20composition%20tends%20to%200&source=gbs_navlinks_s), page $365$ reads:

> Since $\varphi(s)<s$ for $s\in (0,1)$ it follows that the sequence $\varphi^n(s)$ is monotonically decreasing, and we easily see that it tends to $0$ for each $s\in (0,1)$
>
> $($here $\varphi^n (s)$ denotes $\varphi(\varphi(\cdots \varphi(s)\cdots ),\;n$ times, where $\varphi $ is continuous $(0,1)\to(0,1))$

I don't understand why it is "easy" to see that $\varphi^n(s)\to 0$. What prevents it from converging to some $0<\lambda <1?$ I am guessing continuity will come into play, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\varphi(s)<s$ for $s\in(0,1)$ with $\varphi:(0,1)\to(0,1)$ continuous. Let $s\in (0,1)$ be fixed. By the condition on $\varphi$, $s>\varphi(s)>\varphi(\varphi(s))=\varphi^2(s)>\varphi^3(s)>\cdots$, so $\varphi^n(s)$ converges to some $\lambda\in[0,1)$.

By contradiction, suppose that $\lambda>0$. Then $\lambda=\lim\varphi^n(s)$ in $(0,1)$. By continuity, we obtain $\varphi(\lambda)=\lim \varphi^{n+1}(s)=\lim\varphi^n(s)=\lambda>\varphi(\lambda)$, a contradiction.

Therefore, $\varphi^n(s)\rightarrow 0$.